# Div toggle in Rails 4 with coffeescript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a view in which, for a range of objects, I have several divs containing detailed information. For each div I have a Toggle link. My problem is that the toggle() only works for the first kind of divs, the first click event registered. Here is the code:

```
$(".class1").click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()

    #get the index value I appended to this elements ID
    divIndex = $(this).attr("id").replace("link1_", "")

    #select and toggle the respective message
    $("#div1_" + divIndex).toggle()
return

$(".class2").click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()

    #get the index value I appended to this elements ID
    divIndex = $(this).attr("id").replace("link2_", "")

    #select and toggle the respective message
    $("#div2_" + divIndex).toggle()
return
```

It only works for the first click event registered. If I change the order, the other starts working. For the second one, it just follows the link in the view.

Any help please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this code snippet is from within another function body? Try removing the `return` statements. Since they are not nested within your coffee script function body, they refer to the function you have on top level.